# Replicate 'ON DELETE SET NULL' behavior from combination of two non-unique columns on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

## The Situation

I have a full-stack web application with two MySQL tables: `channel_strips` and `mic_lookup`.

```
DESCRIBE `channel_strips`;

Field           Type            Null    Key
preset_id       varchar(127)    NO      PRI 
mic_function    varchar(225)    YES
phantom_power   tinyint(1)      YES
...
```

```
DESCRIBE `mic_lookup`;

Field           Type            Null    Key
Microphone      varchar(40)     NO      PRI 
mic_function    varchar(225)    NO
phantom_power   tinyint(1)      NO
...
(many other columns)
```

**I want** the `channel_strips` table to always hold *only* combinations of `mic_function` and `phantom_power` values that can be *currently* found in the `mic_lookup` table (or null values).

#### What *is* working

On the HTML end, I've limited the input to these columns in `channel_strips` with a `<select>` element that gets values from this mysqli query: `` SELECT DISTINCT `mic_function`, `phantom_power` FROM `mic_lookup`; `` This successfully restricts the user input.

## The Problem

The one situation I've identified where this fails is when entries are deleted or changed in `mic_lookup` such that one pre-existing combination of `mic_function` and  `phantom_power` is eliminated. As a result, `channel_strips` could still have a combination of the two columns that is actually no longer an option. In this situation, **I'd like** those two columns to be nullified on rows where they hold the old combination, essentially emulating an `ON DELETE SET NULL` statement as if it were a foreign key.

#### What I've tried

For a while, I had an intermediate table, `mic_functions` with a single column, `mic_function`, which served as a foreign key to both tables' `mic_function` columns.  However, this was before I realized that `phantom_power` needed to be included.  Furthermore, it was very confusing from a user's perspective, since intuitively you would want to set these values in the `mic_lookup` table.

My next idea was to create a view instead so I'd have a 'table' that automatically updates, and reference that as a foreign key - maybe something like...

```
CREATE VIEW mic_functions AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `mic_function`,
        `phantom_power`
    FROM
        `mic_lookup`
);
ALTER VIEW mic_functions ADD CONSTRAINT PK_mic_function PRIMARY KEY(`mic_function`, `phantom_power`);
```

Of course, this doesn't work. You can't add a primary key to a VIEW.

Finally, I suppose I could write a bunch of php to query and perform a series of checks on `channel_strips` every time the `mic_lookup` table is updated, and execute an appropriate UPDATE query if the checks are violated, but it seems to me like there ought to be a simpler way to handle this on the SQL side of things.  Maybe using SQL checks or triggers or a combination of the two would work, but I have no experience with checks and triggers.

#### Note

`phantom_power` is boolean, and I'm using MySQL version `10.4.21-MariaDB`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using triggers, by joining the tables and filtering down to where the joined primary key is null:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mic_lookup_update` AFTER UPDATE
ON
    `mic_lookup` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE
    `channel_strips` c
LEFT JOIN `mic_lookup` m ON
    c.mic_function = m.mic_function AND c.phantom_power = m.phantom_power
SET
    c.mic_function = NULL,
    c.phantom_power = NULL
WHERE
    m.Microphone IS NULL;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mic_lookup_delete` AFTER DELETE
ON
    `mic_lookup` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE
    `channel_strips` c
LEFT JOIN `mic_lookup` m ON
    c.mic_function = m.mic_function AND c.phantom_power = m.phantom_power
SET
    c.mic_function = NULL,
    c.phantom_power = NULL
WHERE
    m.Microphone IS NULL;
```